# How can I drag a button that's on a canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I spent the last few days trying to figure how I could use the DragDrop feature in C#'s WPF so I could create a button and drag it around in canvas. I think I am missing someting but after an exhasting effort researching I can't figure out what it is. All I need to do is drag the button around in canvas.

Here is my XAML code:

```
x:Class="DragDrop_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DragDrop_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas" Width = "300" Height= "200" Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin= "10, 0,190,100" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Canvas_Drop">
        <Button Name="btn" Content="Button1" MouseMove="btn_MouseMove" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="btn_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">

        </Button>
    </Canvas>


</Window>
```

And here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace DragDrop_Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Control draggedItem;
        bool IsDragging;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsDragging = false;
        }


        private void Canvas_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsDragging)
                return;

            IsDragging = false;
        }



        private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var dependencyObject = (Button)sender;
            draggedItem = dependencyObject;

            if (!IsDragging) 
                return;
            if (dependencyObject != null && dependencyObject.IsMouseOver)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dependencyObject, dependencyObject, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

        private void btn_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsDragging = true;
            draggedItem = (Button)sender;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810683/moving-buttons-in-a-canvas for specific details regarding dragging of buttons in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, 'drag and drop' is not what you need. It is a method of data transfer, not a location setter. As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Drag-and-drop commonly refers to a method of *data transfer* that
>   involves using a mouse (or some other pointing device) to select one
>   or more objects, dragging these objects over some desired drop target
>   in the user interface (UI), and dropping them

If all you want is to move the button around, you could try using `Canvas.SetTop`/`Canvas.SetLeft` or `TranslateTransform`. Maybe something like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Control draggedItem;
        Point itemRelativePosition;
        bool IsDragging;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsDragging = false;
        }

        private void btn_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            IsDragging = true;
            draggedItem = (Button)sender;
            itemRelativePosition = e.GetPosition(draggedItem);
        }

        private void btn_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsDragging)
                return;

            IsDragging = false;
        }

        private void btn_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsDragging)
                return;

            Point canvasRelativePosition = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);

            Canvas.SetTop(draggedItem, canvasRelativePosition.Y - itemRelativePosition.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(draggedItem, canvasRelativePosition.X - itemRelativePosition.X);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Knowledge is truly power.Thank you very much, it could have taken me weeks to figure out that dragdrop isnt the right way to do this.